# The icon in the options menu does not change

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to change the icon using Xml and code, but android studio loads default icon.Tell me what is my mistake

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.gps_img)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.queryHint = "Current city?"

    searchItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_gps_fixed_24)
    
    searchView.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
}

<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:title="@string/gps"
    android:id="@+id/gps_img"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_gps_fixed_24"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu)` method, write icon change logic inside it, also call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method whenever you want to change menu icon.